# Django Channels deny websocket connection with a custom code

Tags: python, django, django-channels

So I need to deny a websocket connection with a specific code so the client can handle the rejection properly. Currently when you reject a connection with `message.reply_channel({'accept':False})` the client simple gets a `403` error. I can close a connection with a code by using `message.reply_channel({'close':3000})` but that requires for the connection to have been accepted in the first place. If that's the only way to do it then so be it but I feel like there should be a way to reject with a code that I simply can't find.

I'm using Django Channels 1.1.8 so the 2.x release changes don't benefit me unfortunately.